# Closed html class after counter = multiple of 3

Tags: php

How to closed my class in multiple of 3. i don't want to use this

```
if ( $counter  == 3 ||  $counter  == 6 || $counter  == 9 || $counter  == 12) 
    { 
        $output.=' </div>';
    }
```

but i want multiple of 3. like

```
if($counter  == 3 || $counter  == 3n)
```

Comment: If you find the answer yourself please post it as an answer and not as an edit to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a WP question but you would do the following:

```
if ($count % 3 != 0) {
  // code
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809864/find-multiples-of-a-number-in-php)

Comment: your code is not working for me any way thanks i have find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution its so sample but some time mind is sleeping.

before while loop set $counter=0; then increment it in if condition.

here is my all code which repeat my  class after each third counter.

```
 $counter = 1;
 $closed = 0;
if ( $gquery->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $gquery->have_posts() ) { 
          $gquery->the_post();
    if ( $counter % 3 == 1) {
      <div class="wilto-slide row-fluid row-wrap"> 
    $closed++;
    }
    <div class="span4">
          <div class="testimonial testimonial-color">
                <div class="inner">
                      <blockquote>
                          <p><?php echo the_content();?></p>
                       </blockquote>
                  </div>
                   <div class="author">
                         <?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>
                          <p class="name"><?php echo the_title();?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <?php
                      if ( $counter  == 3 || $counter==3*$closed) { ?>
                           </div>
                       <?php }
                      $counter++;
   }
}
```

?>